# Dart lambda/shortland function confusion

Tags: dart

I'm still pretty new to Dart and the syntax of => (fat arrow) still confuses me (I come from C# background).

So in C# fat arrow ( => ) says: *goes to* so for example:

```csharp
Action<string> action1 = (str) => { System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine("Parameter received: " + str.ToString()); }

action1("Some parameter");
```

means: whatever send as parameter to `action1` (if it could be casted to `string`) *goes to*  inner scope (in our case it just printed in `Debug.WriteLine()`

but in Dart it's something different....  (?)

for example in `Future.then`

```dart
ClassWithFutures myClass = new ClassWithFutures();
myClass.loadedFuture.then( 
   (str) => { print("Class was loaded with info: $str"),
   onError: (exp) => { print("Error occurred in class loading. Error is: $exp"); }
);
```

Dart editor warn me that the first and second `print` is: `Expected string literal for map entry key`. I think in C# way that `str` it just name for parameter that will be filled by internal callback that `Future.then` uses to call `onValue` or `onError`

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: there is a missing brace in you example:
```(str) => { print("Class was loaded with info: $str") },```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You need to choose either block syntax or single expression syntax, but not both.

You can't combine `=>` with `{}`.

Your two options are as follows using your example:

```dart
ClassWithFutures myClass = new ClassWithFutures();
myClass.loadedFuture.then( 
  (str) => print("Class was loaded with info: $str"),
  onErrro: (exp) => print("Error occurred in class loading. Error is: $exp")
);
```

or

```dart
ClassWithFutures myClass = new ClassWithFutures();
myClass.loadedFuture.then( 
  (str) { print("Class was loaded with info: $str"); },
  onErrro: (exp) { print("Error occurred in class loading. Error is: $exp"); }
);
```

In both cases, it is just a way to express an anonymous function.

Normally if you want to just run a single expression, you use the => syntax for cleaner and more to the point code. Example:

```dart
someFunction.then( (String str) => print(str) );
```

or you can use a block syntax with curly braces to do more work, or a single expression.

```dart
someFunction.then( (String str) {
  str = str + "Hello World";
  print(str);
});
```

but you can't combine them since then you are making 2 function creation syntaxes and it breaks.

Comment: You can use => with {} when you have multiple expression.                                    (value) => {
                                condition = false,
                                print('periodic timer!')
                              }

Comment: @DB no, it's wrong!
() => {} means "single line expression, returning a Set literal"

Answer (score 62):

In Dart `=> xxx` is just a syntaxic sugar to avoid `{ return xxx; }`. Thus the two following functions are equivalent :

```dart
var a = (String s) => s;
var b = (String s) { return s; } ;
```

You can also use `=>` on method definitions :

```dart
String myFunc(String s) => s;
String myFunc(String s) {
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That syntax works well in a language like javascript and also c# where it supports `(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }` with statement being separated with semi colon. In dart, the fat arrow only supports expression which is shorthand for `{ return expr; }`.
That explains your Error. Your code with the curly brace `(exp) => { print("Error occurred in class loading. Error is: $exp"); }` means you are returning a map, so it expects to see something like `(param) => {"key": "value"}` where key is a string literal.