# How to run multiple functions onClick

Tags: dart

The reason it took me forever to find out is that I don't know how it is called. But I hope if I describe the question here as thoroughly as possible, it will pop up in the search results anyways.

Possible other titles:

**How can I pass a function without name as parameter to querySelector.onClick.listen?**

**How to use a function without a name in dart?**

**How to create a nameless function that you can use only exactly there where it is defined?**

---

I know that the following works - also hosted on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/526d5c0f98d40e0847b7)

```
void main(){ querySelector('#btn').onClick.listen((e)=>fnct()); }

void fnct(){   querySelector('#btn').text="hola"; print("test");}
```

This changes the text of the button to "hola" and prints "test".
But what if I don't want to define a new function just for this because I like to keep the flow when reading the code and don't like to jump from function to function needlessly?

Comment: Searching for `dart anonymous function` would probably have given you better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour of searching, I found [this](https://books.google.ch/books?id=EcvjAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=queryselector.onclick.listen+multiple+calls+dart&source=bl&ots=eD_2eK6FdP&sig=GR7uKylN_94B-Z3H8j0CpDO69Ks&hl=de&sa=X&ei=rU2VVbGEFeXSyAOU6qOADg&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=queryselector.onclick.listen%20multiple%20calls%20dart&f=false)

For my own code example, it would be like [this dartpad link](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ba7527d4f6d5d892cd40):

```
void main(){
querySelector('#btn').onClick.listen((e){
  querySelector('#btn').text="hello";
  print("no hablo espanol");
                                        });
}
```

So you can define a function on the flow by using

```
(param){command(); secondCommand(param);}
```

It is entirely possible that you can find this somewhere. But I did not with my search terms. So if any of you know what the correct search terms would have been, let me know :)

Comment: Maybe "lambda" or "inline function". This might be interesting to you as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804101/dart-lambda-shortland-function-confusion. In Dart it's good practice to use short hand function syntax for one-line functions.