# Fat Arrow notation with curly braces in setState Dart/Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am very new to Dart/Flutter and I have a confusion regarding the => notation. The documentation says that the => notation is used as a shorthand to return a single expression.

> bool isNoble(int atomicNumber) => _nobleGases[atomicNumber] != null;

My doubt comes when I am trying to set state in a flutter application.

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () => {
    setState(() {
      print('hello');
      _products.add('More stuff');
    })
  },
  child: Text('Add Product'),
),
```

Now when i change the setState method with => notation

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () => {
    setState(() => {
      print('hello'),
      _products.add('More stuff'),
    })
  },
  child: Text('Add Product'),
),
```

Both methods mentioned above work, that is they set the state as expected. All i had to do was change the semicolons to commas when using the fat arrow notation.

What is the logic behind this ? How is the fat arrow notation working with curly braces which contains multiple expressions within it.

**Edit**

As mentioned by Hemanth Raj the => returns a set and the code segment containing the => notation can be written as follows.

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () => {
    setState(() {
     return {
       print('hello'),
       _products.add('More stuff'),
     };
    })
  },
  child: Text('Add Product'),
),
```

How is the returned `set` containing a print function and _products.add actually updating the state. Shouldn't it throw some kind of error because usually setState is done by an expression such as  `_products.add('More stuff');`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dart lambda/shortland function confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804101/dart-lambda-shortland-function-confusion)

Comment: This is not the duplicate, it is a quite interesting question @MazinIbrahim. This is a result of new way of defining `Set` introduced in `Dart 2.2`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is one of the interesting questions that I would love to answer.

As the official documents say [here](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#functions), yes `=>` is used as a shorthand syntax to `{ return ... }` which means `=>` will just return whatever is produced on the righthand side.

Also from `Dart 2.2` and above, a `Set` can be defined with comma separated values enclosed in a `{}` as mentioned in docs [here](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#sets).

Hence, the syntax you are using, i.e `{}` with statements separated with a comma, it is treated as a `Set` by the `=>` functions. Each element being a function call, `() => { f(a) , f(b), g(a),}` would return a `Set` with the elements returned by each function call.

This example might help you understand what is happening under the hood:

```
dynamic reflect(dynamic a){
  return a;
}

void main() {  
    Function shortHand = () => {reflect(1),reflect('a'),reflect({}),reflect([]),}; // this function when called will return a Set<dynamic>
    print(shortHand().runtimeType); // will print `_LinkedHashSet<dynamic>`
}
```

So the syntax

`() => '...'` returns a `String`,

`() => [ ... , ..., ...]` returns a `List`

and similarly `() => { ... , ... , ... }` actually returns a `Set`

*Note: This method of returning set with comma separated function calls is not recommended, would request you also not to use it unless you wanted a `Set` to be returned as result*

---

**Reply to the Edit :**

Let me breakdown the function call and results for you. So your code goes like this,

```
() => {
    setState(() {
     return {
       print('hello'),
       _products.add('More stuff'),
     };
    })
  }
```

Here the `=>` returns a `Set` with the result of `setState`, i.e it'll return `{ (result of setState call) }` which might be `{ null }`

As you have call `setState` the below code gets executed, which again returns a `Set` with `{ (result of print), (result of _product.add), }`

```
() {
      return {
        print('hello'),
        _products.add('More stuff'),
      };
    }
```

State will update, as you are executing `_products.add('More stuff')`, where `'More stuff'` will be added to `_products` irrespective of where you call it. When `setState` is being called, the widget will be rebuilt with the `_products` with new data added.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please check the edits I've made in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am still confused as to how the widget state is being set inside a return statement. Is it because all functions and expressions run inside the return statement ultimately affect the widget state?

Comment: Yes state will update, as you are executing `_products.add('More stuff')` , where `'More stuff'` will be added to `_products` irrespective of where you call it.

Comment: Also understand, `setState` is being called, the widget will be rebuilt with the `_products` will new data added.

Answer (score 9):

For the record, the recommended syntax for what you are doing is:

```
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        print('hello');
        _products.add('More stuff');
      });
    },
    child: Text('Add Product'),
),
```

The syntax `(args) => { statements }` is *not* how Dart writes function bodies, you do either `(args) { statements }` or `(args) => singleExpression`.

Also, you need to terminate statements with semicolons, `;`, not commas.

As others have pointed out, the syntax you use `(args) => { print("something"), somethingElse }` is actually creating a set (a `Set<void>` because the return type of `print` is `void`) and returning that.

This is a perfect storm of small syntax mistakes, which would seem reasonable to a JavaScript programmer, that comes together to actually mean something completely different in Dart.
And, just to make things even worse, the code *works*. The set literal will evaluate its expression in order, and nobody sees the created set anyway. The syntax just doesn't generalize — you can't change any of the expressions to, say, a for-loop (yet, you will be able to in the next version of Dart).

So, in Dart, never use `=> {` unless you *want* to return a set or map.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. yes i know the recommended approach is what you have suggested. This question arose when i was playing around with the code and something which i believed would not work, worked.