# What's the meaning of “=>” (arrow) in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  [
    Provider<FirebaseAuthService>(
      create: (_) => FirebaseAuthService(),
    ),
    Provider<ImagePickerService>(
      create: (_) => ImagePickerService(),
    ),
  ],
```

What does this syntax (`=>`) mean?

```
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
```

Comment: Hope this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351426/7652758

Answer (score 59, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions):

> For functions that contain just one expression, you can use a
> shorthand syntax. The `=>` *expr* syntax is a shorthand for `{ return expr; }`. The `=>` notation is sometimes referred to as *arrow* syntax.
>
> Note: Only an expression—not a statement—can appear between the arrow
> (=>) and the semicolon (;). For example, you can’t put an if statement
> there, but you can use a conditional expression.

---

**Code example:**

The following function:

```
int sum(int x, int y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

can be rewritten using the arrow function syntax as follows:

```
int sum(int x, int y) => x + y;
```

**Additional example**

```dart
String checkNumber(int x) => x > 10 ? "Number is greater than 10" : "Number is less than or equal to 10";
```

is equivalent to:

```dart
String checkNumber(int x) {
  return x > 10 ? "Number is greater than 10" : "Number is less than or equal to 10";
}
```

Keep in mind that if your function is complex and requires multiple expressions or statements, you will need to use the traditional function declaration syntax with curly braces `{}`.

---

Additionally, if you select the actual arrow function (`=>`) in Android Studio and click on the yellow Bulb icon, you will have the option to "convert to block body":

[image]

And vice versa for converting from an arrow function to simply `return`.

Comment: I have a question when we are using stateful object we usually have that notation for example? `State<CartPage> createState() => _CartPageState();`. I have tried to replace it with return but it didn't work. Does it mean it has a different meaning too?

where `_CartPageState` is a class that extends `State`

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue I just tested and it works for me. Don't forget to add the `return` keyword within the `{}`

Comment: Yeap it was my mistake it worked geeat too