# Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]'. Try adding a selector

Tags: flutter, list, dart

```dart
TextField(
              controller: _searchController,
              onChanged: (value) => {
               List<Job> filtedList  = _jobsList.where((job)=>job.data.companyCode.contains(value)).toList()   
              },
)
```

[image]
[image]

what i wanna do here is just filter a list, but vscode complains about the above error.
if I change to var ,also some errors occurred, what I did wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try removing `=>`

```
 onChanged: (value) {
               List<Job> filtedList  = _jobsList.where((job)=>job.data.companyCode.contains(value)).toList();
}
```

`=>` operator doesn't required `{}` enclosures, it return one liner code.

[Can refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65343998/14533228)

Comment: I think in javascript , this is ok, right? kind of different