# Loop through a list of custom type into another list of objects

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, custom-type

Any efficient way (simplify the code or not using a method but a variable expression) for the same result?

```
static List<Tab> myTabs() {
List<String> des = customType.map((e) => e.description).toList() ;
List<Tab> result = [];
for (var d in des) {
  result.add(Tab(text: d));
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Just directly adding the `Tab` widget to a list

```dart
static List<Tab> myTabs() {
  return customType.map((e) => Tab(text: e.description)).toList();
}
```

Or even use the [fat arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65343818/12349734) (`=>`) syntax:

```dart
static List<Tab> myTabs() => customType.map((e) => Tab(text: e.description)).toList();
```

Comment: or `static List<Tab> myTabs =  customType.map((e) => Tab(text: e.description)).toList();
`

Comment: `List<Tab> myTabs = [
  for (var e in customType) Tab(text: e.description)
];
`