# Why use Dart's "Fat Arrow" =>?

Tags: dart

I am new to Dart, and came across the "Fat Arrow", and found it odd.

I understand what the "Fat Arrow" does, but I don't understand why I should use it.

Searching on the web showed claims that "it's optimizing" or "more streamlined", but this seems a bit of a stretch to me.

`=>` and `{}` are the same number of characters when typing, and it seems a whole lot more readable to surround the function with curly braces.

Why would someone favor the fat arrow over curly brackets? (Or do they?)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you also save the `return` if all the function does is return the result of a single expression

Comment: Not the same number of characters, with `{}` you need to put semicolon after the expression, and if you need the returned value, you would have to write `return` (so `=> expr` is equivalent to `{return expr;}`). I personally favor it when the expression is not too long and want to make it one-liner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65343998/707111

Comment: Okay, sure, you are all correct, I didn't count the letters in `return`. Is there some other deeper reason to prefer `=>`? It seems like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: Makes the code much easier to read. There are lot of cases where you just want to use a single one-statement argument to methods and it gets quickly very annoying if you need to add brackets and a return statement. E.g. if you are calling `map()` on lists.

Comment: See [this example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e1b5cd0b45984e17c9f007333691bc0b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `=>` for functions when it makes the function more readable.

A function body of `=> expression;` is exactly equivalent to a function body of `{ return expression; }`, except when the return type is `void`.

That means that you *do* save characters using `=>`, because you can omit the `return` . And with the standard Dart formatter, `=> expression;` can be fit on one line where

```
 ... {
  return expression;
}
```

always take three lines.

So, brevity. Which may or may not translate into readability.

The `void`-return-type exception is that you *are* allowed to write:

```dart
  void log(String s) => print("LOG: $s");
```

but not

```dart
  void log(String s) {
    return print("LOG: $s");  // NOT ALLOWED
  }
```

The latter is disallowed for your own safety, it looks like you try to return a value, and a `void`-return-type function should be treated as if it doesn't return a value. Nobody will ever *look* at that value.

That's not a problem, you can just write:

```dart
  void log(String s) {
    print("LOG: $s");
  }
```

instead, no `return` required. Or if it's in the middle of something, you can, and *should*, do:

```dart
  // ...
  if (something) {
    print("ERROR: Bad thing happened");
    return;
  }
```

instead of `return print("ERROR: Bad thing happened");`. (This has been used as a way to save one line, but it's bad for readability, and the authors should feel bad.)

The reason the language has this difference is that people *like* the "one liner" property of `=>` so much that they want it for simple functions that don't return something, like *setters* or similar one-line functions:

```dart
  void set foo(int x) => _x = x;
  void log(String text) => print("LOG: $text");
```

(Setters must have a `void` return type, so you are allowed and encouraged to omit the `void`, but it's still a `void` return type.)

To give people that one-liner abilitt, the language allows you to write such `void`-`=>` functions, knowing that the value will be lost. The `void` and `=>` are usually close enough together in the source that a reader can clearly see the connection, unlike a long `void ... { ...many lines... return e; }` function.

I personally prefer to not use `=>` for `void`-returning functions, because I still find it easier to quickly grok what a function does, even if not by a lot.