# What is the different between these two void methods in Dart?

Tags: dart

**Code:**

```
void main() {  runApp(MyApp());}
```

**And**

**Code:**

```
Void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

Comment: Check out this other 3 posts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65343818/8745788 https://stackoverflow.com/q/55350820/8745788 https://stackoverflow.com/q/15804101/8745788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I will go with the detailed explanation it might help you with depth.**

Functions in Dart behave much like function in JavaScript. They can be defined as a method similar to our void function, as well as, they behave like first-class objects meaning they can be stored in a variable, passed as an argument or returned like a normal return value of a function.

---

[image]

---

As you can see from the above example, there are many ways to create a function. A function that does not define a return type (like using var syntax) has a return type of dynamic. If parameters in function definition have no types, they implicitly have the dynamic type.

**Fat Arrow Expression**
Fat Arrow Expression or Lambda Function Expression is a syntax to write a function on a single line `using => syntax` AKA fat arrow. This resembles the `ES6` Fat Arrow function syntax of JavaScript. This is a cleaner way to write functions with a single statement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is very little difference.

A function of the form `SomeType name(args) => expression;` is almost entirely equivalent to `SomeType name(args) { return expression; }`.

Dart's `void` type is slightly different from other similar language's use of `void`. The type is not an *empty* type, instead it's equivalent to `Object?` in that it can contain any value, it just statically prevents you from using the value.
This design was chosen originally in Dart 1 because it allowed a method returning a useful value to override a method which returned `void`.

Dart generally disallows a `return value;` statement in a `void` returning function, because it's probably a mistake, unless the type of `value` is itself `void` (or `dynamic` or `Null`).

So

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

is equivalent to

```dart
void main() {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}
```

but since `main` has a return type of `void` (*and* because it's the main method), no-one is ever going to *look* at the returned value.

So, in short, you can use `=> voidExpression;` as shorthand for  `{ voidExpression;}` because no-one is going to notice the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a difference in terms of logic.

We use:

```
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

when the function just uses a single line. However, we use the angle brackets "{}" to indicate a complication of different lines.

For example:

```
     void main() { 
         runApp(MyApp());
     }
```

Notice the use of more than one line.

Usually in your case, you wouldn't use the second method and id suggest you stick to the first one.

Hope it helped! :)